# Is there a fix for keyboard freezing in Ubuntu Studio 20.04.x?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, xorg, input

Can any of users share a workaround/fix for keyboard input stopping from time to time in Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS, I would apreciate the suggested fixes.

That is the exact question - to share the solution or a workaround to this annoyance.

P.S. it persists across any kernel updates for a long time.

System:

- Ubuntu Studio 20.04.x LTS (.1 initially)
- XORG X11 xorg-server 2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2
- XFCE 4.16 repo and upgraded from default XFCE 4.14
- only one screensaver and that is X-screensaver (XFCEs screensaver was freezing the whole machine, so it is shut off even to autorun)
- Intel Core i5 CPU, Intel 3000 embedded gfx
- 16GB RAM
- Wine and Anbox subsystems installed

Comment: There is no such issue as "keyboard freezing in Ubuntu Studio 20.04.x". It can be a hardware issue, or other reasons.

Comment: running ubuntu studio on my lenovo laptop works fine while my main pc freezes on installation. Sometimes it is just better to chose something else instead to try to find a fix for some curious problem

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree with @Pilot6 - no bug like that in windows whatsoever -  I confirm the bug in Ubuntu Studio 20.04.x - freezing of keyboard is noticeable after getting back to the machine after some period of time, or when unlocking the Xscreensaver (which activates after machine was not used for a period of time. Now, what is usable is the concrete answer without assuming that OS components are bulletproof against bugs that cause erratic behaviour - as this issue is, I assure you, very real. Thank you.